# React Native Expo, write code for specific plateform

Tags: react-native, expo

I am currently buidling a react native app with expo xde.

I was wondering how to write specific platform code for Android only or IOS only.
Expo does not create neither an Android nor an IOS file but a main.js

I understand that the purpose of expo is to make your app fully crossplateform. 
But if, as example, I want to tell my Android app to open the playstore and my Iphone app to open the appstore, how do I do that ?

Thanks by advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a guide here of how to do this with React Native generally:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

Both techniques outlined in the guide will work with Expo without you doing anything special.

Basically, you can either do stuff like:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios')  {
    return <Text>I'm on iOS</Text>;
} else {
    return <Text>I'm on Android</Text>;
}
```

or you can write files like `MyComponent.ios.js` and `MyComponent.android.js` and when you do `require('MyComponent')` or `import MyComponent from './MyComponent'` then the right file will be included automatically.